# How do I fix this CSS code? I need to replace content using CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

So this is my code below, for the following page (see screenshot):

[image: Screenshot of my client's website]

**I am trying to replace 'Replay course' with the words 'Access course'.
What am I doing wrong?**

```
a.course-card__resume {
display: none;
}
    
a.course-card__resume:after {
content: 'Access Course';
}
```

Comment: Your CSS is probably being overwritten by something else, regardless though; this won't work. You're displaying your `a` tag as `none`, this will apply to your `::after` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change content solely using CSS, you need access to the HTML at least, or the ability to write JS if not.

See below for a CSS solution, although this will require you to edit your HTML to include another tag.

```css
a span {
  display:none;
}

a::after {
  content:'Access Course';
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Replay Course</span></a>
```

Alternatively, if you have the ability to add JS code; see below.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("course-card__resume")[0].innerText = "Access Course";
```

```html
<a href="#" class="course-card__resume">Replay Course</a>
```

You haven't provided your full code, so I can't be sure if this solution will work for you, but see below. It takes advantage of the `visibility` css rule, but also requires you to use `absolute` positioning.

```css
a {
  visibility:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
a::after {
  content:'Access Course';
  visibility:visible;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Replay Course</a>
```

Comment: The JS looks good! But I don't have an ID, can I use the class name instead? I wrote this. 

document.getElementsByClassName('course-card__resume').innerText = "Access Course";

Comment: @JustinLight Use this `document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].innerText = "Access Course";`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```css
a.course-card__resume:after {
  content: 'Access Course';
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you make the element disappear by display:none. The after element will not be displayed too, because it's dependency doesnt exist.
Maybe you want to try this:

```css
a.course-card__resume {
visibility: hidden;
}
    
a.course-card__resume:after {
content: 'Access Course';
visibility: visible;
}
```